# PDF of a function with two noise sources

Tags: probability-distributions

I have the following function:
$$h(t)=L(t)\dfrac{EFL}{d_0-v(t)t}$$
$EFL$ and $d_0$ are know constants. $L(t)=L_0+\nu(t)$ and $v(t)=v0+w(t)$ where $L_0$ and $v_0$ are constant. $\nu(t)$ and $w(t)$ are random variables normally distribuited. So:
$$\nu(t)=\mathcal{N(0,\sigma_0)}$$ and $$w(t)=\mathcal{N(0,\sigma_1)}.$$
What is the PDF of $h(t)$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to consider $h(t)$ as a function of two independent random variables
$$
   g(t)=\nu(t)
$$
and
$$
   h(t)=(L_0+\nu(t))\frac{EFL}{d_0-v_0t-w(t)t}.
$$
Then, the Jacobian is given by
$$
   J=\frac{t}{EFL}\frac{h^2}{L_0+g}.
$$
Then, the distribution becomes
$$
   P(h,g)=\frac{t}{EFL}\frac{h^2}{L_0+g}\frac{1}{\sigma_0\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{g^2}{2\sigma_0^2}}\frac{1}{\sigma_1\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_1^2t^2}\left(d_0-v_0t-EFL\frac{L_0+g}{h}\right)^2}.
$$
Your distribution will be given by
$$
   H(h)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(h,g)dg.
$$